# Help with understanding "Assume for infinitely amount of $n$, the sequence $s_n=t_n$"

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was wondering whether anyone could help with the follow problem:

Let the sequence $s_n$ converge to $s$ and $t_n$ converge to $t$

Assume for infinitely amount of $n$, the sequence $s_n=t_n$.

Show the limit $s=t$

I am difficulty in understanding what is meant with the "assume for infinitely amount of $n$, the sequence $s_n=t_n$"

If they aren't the same sequence does it mean one of them is a subsequence? Or does it mean something different?

Comment: Let $M=\{n\in\Bbb N:s_n=t_n\}$; they’re saying that $M$ is an infinite set. In other words, there is an infinite sequence that is a subsequence of both $\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle t_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Comment: Aha great! So the way I would go about proving it would be prove that since sn converges to s, its subsequence must also converge to s. And since tn converges to t, its subsequence converges to t. And since there is an infinite sequence that is a subsequence of both sn and t then s=t?

Comment: It's like the sequences $\frac{1}{2n}$ and $\frac{1}{3n}$. They have infinite common values: $\frac{1}{6n}$.

Comment: @Sirius: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that who wrote that meant that, for infinitely many $n$'s, we have $s_n=t_n$. But it's not a good way of expressing that.